# Symfony 4: match route only when there is no subdomain

Tags: symfony4, symfony-routing

I want to match a route only when there is no subdomain in the url:

Here is the route where I match the subdomain being "api"

```
/**
 * @Route("/properties/save", host="api.{host}", name="api_property_save",requirements={"host"=".*"},methods={"PUT"})
 */
public function saveApi()
{
...
```

Here I would like to match only if there is no subdomain specified.

```
/**
 * @Route("/properties/save", name="property_save")
 */
public function save()
{
...
```

Comment: Here is some examples https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/hostname_pattern.html#using-placeholders

Comment: thanks, I looked into the symfony docs, but there is no example for when i target specifically the "no subdomain" case.

Comment: Defined host doesn't work? `* @Route("/properties/save", host="{host}", name="property_save")`